# Troubleshooting a Win10 Bluescreen with no dump file

Tags: windows-10, crash

This just started happening a few days ago. The computer briefly pulls up a screen saying it encountered a problem and needs to restart, and then it restarts.

I can't read a dump file because "Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation."
Another thing i noticed in the event log is that it's recording the unexpected shutdown at the wrong time.
"The previous system shutdown at 7:31:36 PM on ‎9/‎6/‎2020 was unexpected." It actually crashed at around 8:11pm
But the timestamps on the event log entries after the reboot are showing the correct time. And I haven't noticed the system clock showing the wrong time.

The last thing in the event log prior to the crash is this (and it appears multiple times a day):
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
{2593F8B9-4EAF-457C-B68A-50F6B8EA6B54}
and APPID
{15C20B67-12E7-4BB6-92BB-7AFF07997402}
to the user MYPCNAME\MYUSERNAME SID (S-1-5-21-1186387186-3346954459-1088633368-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

This entry starts appearing in the event log prior to the crashes starting

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Or at least figure out the cause? I can't think of anything that changed a few days ago. I don't remember installing any new software, or changing any windows settings.

Comment: Try updating all the Drivers with the manufacturer's Driver Update App (should include BIOS), and then see (a) if that fixes it or (b) creates a minidump file on crash. Windows 10 will normally make a useful minidump file.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the bsod details on the crash screen, use regedit to modify the registry, go to this location in the registry

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl

make new dword

> DisplayParameters

set to 1

reboot.

Now you will get the old bsod screen with details if it does bsod.

In addition to this you can have the bsod screen stay up until you force shutdown the PC, right click on the my PC icon and select properties, then go to the advanced system settings on the left, next click the startup and recovery settings button.

In here Un tick the "automatically restart" box, then apply.

Now when it bsods you will get a screen with some details and it will stay up so you can write it down to do some google research.

Note: crash dumps are written to the page file (Windows Vitual Memory), so if there are issues or corruption with the Windows page file, that is why no dump is written.

To create a new page file, disable the page file, reboot, enable the page file, reboot.

Comment: Actually, i have a suspicion as to the cause - the PSU. After going through my email receipts to see when i bought the various parts of my system, most of them are 2 years old or newer, but i realized the PSU is from 2013. Does a 7 year old PSU seem like a likely culprit? It's a seasonic x650 gold.

Comment: They wont cause a bsod that I have ever heard of.

Comment: well, i made the changes so I can see any error that appears on the screen. I haven't had another crash yet though so no error message to report yet.

Comment: So it crashed the other day, with the error: unexpected_store_exception. I ran the windows memory diagnostic, as well as the SSD tools from samsung to test my SSD. Mem test was clean and the only thing the samsung tool came up with was an available firmware update for my SSD, but as far as I can tell, the update just enables encryption, which i am not using. It doesn't look like the firmware update fixes any problems, so I didn't bother applying it.

Comment: See this>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x154--unexpected-store-exception